# Blur button after click of the button

Tags: button, angularjs

I am using AngularJS in a Salesforce implementation. there is a button which when clicked does few automations in Salesforce - all good there. But the automation takes about 3-5 seconds to finish thus prompting users to click the button more than once.

My requirement is after the click of the button, user should not be able to click the same button again. It should blur the button after the click of the button.

Any help on this is very much appreciated - Thanks.

My code:

```
<div ng-show="ForRegistration">
            <input type="button" ng-click="saveLead( true );" ng-dbclick="" ng-disabled="myForm.$pristine || myForm.$dirty && myForm.$invalid" value="Continue" class="btn btn-default" role="button"/>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could show a processing modal until the server request is completed instead of disabling the button.

In this case, showing modal is a better option considering the UX Experience and also we are notifying the user, there's an operation going on, and he has to wait(he wouldn't be able to click on any buttons because of the modal overlay).

For example:

```
<apex:page>
    <style>
        .modal {
                position:   absolute;
                z-index:    1000;
                top:        0;
                left:       0;
                height:     100%;
                width:      100%;
                background: rgba(255, 255, 255,0.91) 
                    url('{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS202,'/assets/images/spinners/slds_spinner_brand.gif')}') //any loading img 
                    scroll 50% 50% no-repeat;  
                background-size: 60px 60px;
            }
    </style>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TestController">
        <form name="myForm">
            <input type="button" ng-click="saveLead( true );" ng-dbclick="" value="Continue" class="btn btn-default" role="button"/>
        </form>

        <div class="modal" ng-show="processing"></div>
    </body>

    <script>
        (function() {

            "use strict";

            angular.module('myApp', [])
            .controller('TestController', function($scope) {
                $scope.processing = false;

                $scope.saveLead = function() {
                    $scope.processing = true;
                    //Call your server side action

                    //once above is done, hide the modal
                     $scope.processing = false;
                }
            });
        })();
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**NOTE**: Above modal hiding logic works well in synchronous call, but if you are using remote action method, then wrapping this line `$scope.$apply(function(){$scope.processing = false;})` in it's callback.